# Reset presentation detail is using Standard values from wrong / old template

Tags: presentation, templates

I'm trying to migrate a Sitecore page to use a new template with new presentation details in it's Standard values.  This template inherits from the currently used template.

When I change the page to use the new template, I expect that it would now use the presentation of the new template's Standard values. However it seems to always keep the presentation details of the original template.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Which Sitecore version you are on? Apart from Standard values do you have any more differences in new/old template which are not carried over ?

Comment: Is the item still using the standard values of the old template or has it been modified, i.e. have you added any additional renderings to the item?

Comment: I created std values on the new template that update the presentation.  This new presentation is not being applied upon changing to the new template.  Even after resetting the layout (to reset any user overrides)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you make a change to a field on an item, the link between that item and its `Standard Value` is effectively broken. Since the `Renderings` and `Final Renderings` field which are used for Shared/Final Layout are just regular Sitecore fields, the same applies to the `Presentation Details` which you set on the Standard Values, i.e. if you have made a change to the item by adding/removing renderings (for example) then you have broken the link.

In order to restore the link back to the Standard Values you can `Reset` the layout fields. Be sure to select the Renderings and/or Final Renderings fields as needed.

Word of warning, it will **reset** the layout and remove any additional Renderings that may have been added by you users. If you need them on the page, you will need to add them back in.

**From the Experience Editor:**

[image: Reset Layout in Experience Editor]

**From the Content Editor:**

[image: Reset Layout in Content Editor]

You could also write a PowerShell script to [Reset-Layout](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/appendix/commands/Reset-Layout.html) of items if you have a lot of items.

Comment: I tried resetting the layout, then changing the template again.  I only ever get the presentation from the original (base) template.

Comment: If you have it installed you can also try using Sitecore Rocks. You can select one or more items and under Tasks there is a reset layout option.

Comment: @RReilley I don't see how to do this in sitecore rocks.  I'm running  
2.1.86.  This post shows how to do it but I don't see the Layouts item in the menu.  Also not sure why this would work in rocks but not in the content editor .   
2.1.86

Comment: When you did you connection for your site in Sitecore Rocks did you install the Hard Rock Web Service?